# CRT not detecting memory leak in DLL

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, memory-leaks, crt

I developed an application which consists of main executable and dynamic library (dll). Both of them are developed by me and are build with same compiler (FYI: both are contained in same VS solution) on Windows 10 Pro.

When i want to test the executable and library for memory leaks with [MS CRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library) library. I can detect memory leaks in the executable, but not in dynamic library (i intentionally leak in both with one undeleted integer).

Executable is build with MDd and the library is build with MTd. I also tried building the executable with MTd with no success. (Library due to its dependencies must be build with MT(d)). Also please be noted, I do not mean that i have smaller reports of memory leaks (like without filenames and lines), I mean there are no reports for dll when there should be atleast one.

The question is if does anybody had this problem and knows how to solve it.

Comment: Better use Dr Memory: http://drmemory.org/. Unlike MS CRT library which has been known to give false positives on memory leaks, I have found Dr Memory to be much more accurate and informative too

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, I actually tried to use it, but it closed due to the wrong windows version (i added development OS to the question).

Comment: FYI, it's compatible with Windows 10

Comment: Since you link with the CRT statically, the DLL has its own copy and thus its own heap. You can try calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks in DllMain on process detach.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johannes Passing mentioned on his blog post that when DLL is linked to static version of CRT correct place to make explicit memory dumps is DllMain's `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` case.

https://jpassing.com/2008/09/01/effective-leak-detection-with-the-debug-crt-and-application-verifier/

Comment: Thanks, i added setting of crt flags on dll entry (actually not DllMain, but for my use case it is almost the same) and i got the missing leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Your DLL doesn't use MFC? Then there's the problem, the memory leak detection in MFC overrides native C++ new by own allocators and uses that macro mentioned in Microsoft documentation. I'm afraid that you have to re-implement tracking method in .LL if it doesn't use that.. crt lib with  _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC tracks malloc, doesn't touch native `operator new`.

Comment: To my knowledge, MFC is not used, although I use CEF and native window for certain purposes in library.